# PySpark: Exhaustive list of data types

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to define a function in Python Spark that can tell me which columns are to be considered as numeric (continuous) and which should be considered as categorical columns. While doing this I'm accessing the `dtypes` of the dataframe and iterating through each of the variable to check if its a member of `continuous_types` or `categorical_types`(defined below). `continuous_types` and  `categorical_types` are lists and these are their entries-

```
continuous_types = ('double', 'bigint')
categorical_types = ('string')
```

I think there are more strings/`dtypes` that should be a part of both these lists, especially `continuous_types`. I got these `dtypes` by creating and reading datatsets and checking their `dtypes`. Are these three exhaustive?

I looked up [this link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.2/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html) but I couldn't get the required information.

In short, what is the exhaustive list of values I can expect when I access the `dtypes` attribute of a spark dataframe

Comment: You're looking into correct direction. Check all `simpleString` methods in that file!

Answer (score 0):

You find the available types there : 
[pyspark.sql.types](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.types)